# How to decode a pointer from Shelley address?

Tags: address

I'm writing an address parser based on [CIP-0019](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-0019/README.md). The part I have problems with is the `POINTER` data structure which consists of three *"variable-length positive numbers"*. The format of the number is described as:

```
VARIABLE-LENGTH-UINT = (%b1 | UINT7 | VARIABLE-LENGTH-UINT) 
                     / (%b0 | UINT7)
```

So, IIUC, I should read bytes while their oldest bit is `1`, then read one byte more. I should also clear the oldest bits from them. Then I finish with a bunch of `UINT7`.

How should I convert them to the final integer value?

Answer (score 0):

The following Python code does the thing. Iterating from right, those 7-bit UINTs should be cleared of the oldest bit, then shifted right by their right-index.

```
def popvarlenuint(data):
    _intbytes = []
    while data:
        b = data[0]
        data = data[1:]
        _intbytes.append(b & 0x7F)
        if b & 0x80 == 0:
            break
    val = 0
    for idx, b in enumerate(reversed(_intbytes)):
        val = val | (b << (8 * idx) - idx)
    return val, data
```